# Why Light and Observers have different laws of physics

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, spacetime, observers, laws-of-physics

Special relativity states:

- The speed of light in a vacuum is always $c$, regardless of the velocity of the observer.
- The laws of physics are the same for all observers in uniform motion.

These two statements that we know as "special relativity" indicate that $c$ (speed of light) does not follow the same laws of physics as the observer.

- The laws of physics are the same for all observers in uniform motion.
- The observer is (anything that never travels at the velocity $c$).
- The laws of physics are the same for (anything that never travels at the velocity $c$).
- The laws of physics are not the same for anything that does travel at the velocity $c$.

This suggests that when we use our physics to measure and predict light, what we are predicting and measuring is only the disturbance in our physical laws, caused by the passing of something that does not exist within our physical laws. As an analogy, the electromagnetic wave is to the photon as thunder is to lightning. Our physical laws enable us to measure and predict the disturbance in our reality that we know as electromagnetic wave light, but the cause of this electromagnetic wave exists under entirely different laws of physics and therefore a different reality.

Comment: What's wrong with just saying that a ray of light is not a valid observer?

Comment: Nothing, that is a true statement. But since light is not a valid observer, it is also not included in the statement that tells us when the laws of physics are the same. The statement "The laws of physics are the same for all observers in uniform motion" does not tell us anything about the physics of light, because that statement only tells us about the physics of observers. The other statement is about the physics of light, primarily its "speed", and it tells us that no matter what the observer's velocity is, that velocity will never be the speed of light, so there can be no uniform motion.

Comment: It doesn't rule out anything about the physics of light.  It just tells us that we cant' look at physics <b>from the light's perspecive</b>.  It is still 100% consistent to talk about the influences of light rays, and the interaction of the electromagnetic field with matter.  There is just no observer that will be able to look at an electromagnetic wave and say that it is static.  This makes sense, because it would otherwise break Maxwell's equations.

Comment: Special Relativity indicates that uniform motion (or the ability to have uniform motion) is what causes physics to be the same for all observers, and it tells us that light can never be in uniform motion with observers, so there is never a time when the laws of physics would be the same for the two. Where is light included in the statement, "The laws of physics are the same for all observers in uniform motion"? So where do you get the idea that they would be the same for light as for observers? Because some of the math works if you tweak it enough or make enough exceptions?

Comment: Comment to the latest edit (in particular on its form): Mathematics is a constructive language that allows to write (true) statements (within a given theory). Rhetoric is a form of language, and you write statements, but has not much else in common with mathematics/physics...rhetorical questions does not seem the best way to understand mathematical/physical concepts. As John Rennie, I will not write anymore because it seems that there is no constructive improvement. Also, to speak the truth, this whole argument is not so interesting (at least for me).

Comment: I'm voting to close since this question appears to be off-topic because it is about nothing well-defined. You keep throwing words around like "the laws of physics", "existence" and "the photon's universe" without *ever* providing a definition of them, and since your understanding of these words seem to differ significantly from that of every physicist, the question is unanswerable. To me, it makes as much sense as asking "Why does blue taste of unicorns?".

Comment: @ACuriousMind: "_I'm voting to close [...]_" -- I agree with your vote (FWIW while I'm not (yet) permitted to vote on such matters) because the OP has greatly "moved the target" of the question, and not dealt with the substance of answers provided so far. However: "_because it is about nothing well-defined. You keep throwing words around like "the laws of physics", [...]_" -- Well, we can hardly blame the OP when he (Derek Roberts) and the larger public is confronted with ill-defined assertions such as "`A law of physics is just some set of equations that we use to predict what happens.`"

Comment: You're voting to close because you don't like it. If it didn't make sense you wouldn't care and you wouldn't be here. The few of you who weren't too close minded to entertain the notion were very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: "your understanding of these words seem to differ significantly from that of every physicist, the question is unanswerable". Your opinions are so offensive and unscientific, that their aim seems to be closing the mouth of those who do not share your particular understanding of physics.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: " It just tells us that we cant' look at physics from the light's perspecive." I find all these "bans" in physics very suspicious. It seems very metaphysical to me (religious almost). And yet, as I pointed out elsewhere, physics doesn't mind looking at the universe from a black hole's perspective. Here nobody is stopped from trying to figure out the internal logic and coherence with outside world.

Comment: @DerekRoberts: "The title is misleading ... the most advanced experiments to observe and measure a photon only observe how the photon interacts with other things, not the photon itself." You need to be careful, because measurement always means "observing how something interacts with something else". As I understand it, here the atom that the photon (somehow) interacted with was outside the measuring device, yet it does not change things much. Obviously, measurement should be as direct as possible, but still it is always about interaction and then converting this interaction into some readout.

Comment: @brightmagus: True. With a photon, it seems as if we are only able to... even tell that it exists, because it interacts with other things. Even the electromagnetic wave is not directly observable to us, we only see what light illuminates, not light itself. The "space" directly around the Sun is dark because there is not any "thing" there for the light to interact with for us to see.

Comment: @brightmagus: For other things, we're generally able to setup an experiment, view a thing fairly directly at a point in space and time, and make future direct observations to compare change over time. If I'm measuring you, running on a track, I don't have to... measure the air pressure around your body to determine how fast, or from where to where, you traveled. With you, I can just write down where you are, what time you started, where you ended up. With light, and light alone, everything only works in some "roundabout" way, where as with everything else, it's very straight forward.

Comment: @DerekRoberts: Sure, I just meant to point out that the measurements you quote are probably no different than other measurements of this kind, i.e. on sub-atomic level.

Comment: @brightmagus "And yet, as I pointed out elsewhere, physics doesn't mind looking at the universe from a black hole's perspective." AND, two of the assumptions that physicists make about black holes are that inside, time does not exist and gravity is infinite.

Comment: @bright magus: With my opinions being "offensive" (to you), I will gladly live. I am not "closing the mouth" of anyone, I am expressing my belief that this question is not appropiate for this site. I will not hinder you or anyone else to spread your glorious understanding somewhere else.  But this site is in no way obliged to be a soapbox for people doubting the validity of relativity in such a stubborn and unconstructive way. (see our [non-mainstream policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site).

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I don't think this is a place for defining every word used. You should move to Wikipedia instead (not that I am trying to "close your mouth", you know, you just should go "somewhere else" to "spread your glorious" unambiguity). And if you believe a person using the expression "laws of physics" without special explanation is unconstructive, then Einstein would not fit in here either according to your standards. Likewise, if you do not like people to try to understand physics here, you also should go teach in some backward elementary school (again, I am not closing your mouth ...)

Comment: Given that this question has ***drastically*** changed from its [initial incarnation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/127455/1), the answers to this question appear to be no longer relevant and this question should be closed. If you have new questions, based on the original question, [then ask a new one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) but include a link to this one.

Answer (score 11):

To make progress we need to be clear what we mean by *the laws of physics* and *observer*.

A *law of physics* is just some set of equations that we use to predict what happens. So if for example we're trying to describe how charges interact with light our set of equations, i.e. our *law of physics*, would be Maxwell's equations.

But to write down Maxwell's equations and solve them we need to choose a set of coordinates. We need an origin and time and distance vectors. Choosing these chooses a frame of reference, and this then allows us to assign $(t,x,y,z)$ positions to things that happen. The act of *observation* is just the recording of these positions.

So far so good. Now suppose that you and I are making measurements of some system, e.g. an electron, and we're moving relative to each other at some high velocity near $c$. The laws of physics, Maxwell's equations in this case, are the same for both of us but that does not mean we observe the same thing. If the electron is stationary in my frame Maxwell's equations tell me it will have an electrostatic field and that's what I will measure. In your frame the electron will be moving and Maxwell's equations tell you it has both electric and magnetic fields and that's what you will measure. So we observe different things even though we're using the same *laws of physics*.

What special relativity tells us is that my observations and your observations are linked by a Lorentz transformation. If I take my observations and Lorentz transform them into your frame they will be the same as what you observe. This is always the case for all physicists moving at any speed relative to us of less than $c$. This is what we mean when we say the laws of physics are the same for all observers. It does not mean they all observe the same thing, only that their observations are all equivalent in that they are linked by a Lorentz transformation.

Now on to the key part of your question. What happens in a frame of reference moving at a speed of $c$ relative to us?

Well, there's a get out clause. If you take my example above as a reference we can never observe an electron moving at the speed of light relative to us, because accelerating an electron to $c$ would require infinite energy. So while we can ask what measurements are made in a reference frame traveling at 0.9$c$ or 0.999999999$c$, the question *what measurements are made in a frame travelling at $c$* is meaningless - no such measurements can be made. Just as well really, because the Lorentz transformations become singular at a relative velocity of $c$ so we couldn't do the calculation anyway.

But of course light travels at $c$. However this doesn't mean the laws of physics are different for light, it just means we can't write down Maxwell's equations in a reference frame travelling at the speed of light relative to us. But that's OK because light can't make measurements so there's nothing to use Maxwell's equations to predict. Only we massive things can make measurements, and we can't attain relative speeds equal to $c$.

Going back to your question, your last point 4 states:

> The laws of physics are not the same for anything that does travel at the velocity $c$.

The trouble with this is that the obvious interpretation is:

> The laws of physics **do not apply to** anything that does travel at the velocity $c$.

which is obviously wrong because the behaviour of light is well described by Maxwell's equations, and as we've seen Maxwell's equations are the same in all (sub-luminal) reference frames. On the other hand if you wrote instead:

> Maxwell's equations cannot be written down in a reference frame travelling at a relative velocity of $c$.

then this I would have to agree with. But while this may seem startling to non-physicists, for us physicists well that's kind of obvious and it's just how the universe is.

Answer (score 3):

I will expand my comment above into an answer, but I will not comment further on it to avoid the usual very long discussions of your posts.

In my opinion, you are trying to argue on a logical level, but it is not clear if you have enough knowledge of [logical theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_(mathematical_logic)) to do so on a mathematical/physical level.

Without entering too much into details, a mathematical theory consists of a collection of objects and symbols that define the formal language, a collection of sentences in the formal language (the axioms) and a collection of inference rules that tells how formal sentences can be combined to obtain other sentences.
This rigorous approach is often relaxed, and more discursive (informal) proofs and statements are allowed (however formalizable, i.e. reducible to formal statements and proofs).

The connection with your question is the following: special relativity is not a complete logic theory by itself, it is only a set of axioms (call this set $SR$), independent of the others, within some more complete logical theory. They are independent in the sense that there is no other axiom $P\notin SR$ such that $P\implies Q$, $Q\in SR$. These axioms are more precisely schemes, in the sense that they are rules that apply to the objects of the logical theory, but do not define any ad hoc new object.

In particular "light", "photon", "laws of physics" etc. are not defined by special relativity. Their existence is not related to special relativity, the latter just gives some rules that these objects, provided they are correctly formalized and belong to the theory, must satisfy.

You say that your opinions on the object you call "light" and its "laws of physics" are suggested by special relativity, but as you put them they seem to me completely unrelated to it. Even if you were able to make your ideas into statements that are formally acceptable in some logical theory, you have also to guarantee that at least part of your objects satisfy the axioms and schemes of $SR$, if you would like to have a theory that contains special relativity, and that is not unrelated to it. If you are able to do so, and obtain by means of your theory (at least a part of) the predictions that the usually accepted physical theories are able to predict, and in addition something different, that is verifiable experimentally, then you would have every physicist's attention. If else you are only doing philosophical speculation, metaphysics or call it whatever you like, but not mathematics/physics.

**In conclusion**: Since you are looking for something that is not defined in the usually accepted physical theories, your question is mathematically meaningless as it stands. This is unless you define precisely what the "laws of physics", "light" and "observables" are in your theory, which are the objects and axioms, and thus their predictive power. You should then be able to investigate why, within your theory, "light and observables have different laws of physics", because the latter would be then a meaningful sentence (and hopefully true, or at least not false).

Comment: In theory, you wouldn't be able to "predict" something that happened in a universe without time.

Answer (score 3):

OK, just one more try to end this stupid question.

There IS a way to formulate physics using light rays as your basis: a double null coordinate system${}^{1}$.  If you have a ray moving in the $+x$ direction, define the two coordinates

$$2\xi = t + x\;\;\quad\quad\quad2\eta = t - x$$

Then, the metric becomes

$$ds^{2} = -4d\xi \,d\eta + dy^{2} + dz^{2}$$

All measurements can be expressed in this coordinate system.  Individual light rays moving only in the $x$ direction are identified by their constant value of $\xi$ or $\eta$, and rather than measuring the evolution of "time", they see spatial variation through identification of surfaces of varying $\eta$ intersecting with them.

Somehow, I think you're going to be completely unsatisfied with this answer, because you're out to yell about how physics is wrong and physicists are arrogant idolaters with false preconceptions about the universe, and it would be obvious if people just THOUGHT about it, man.

${}^{1}$ In string theory, they call these coordinates light-cone coordinates.  I like this terminology better, as it's clearer and more elucidating, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your notion seems to be based on the thinking that light is a bunch of photons, and a photon is some kind of weird particle that travels at the speed of light, like some tiny spaceship. Then you ask, how can this tiny spaceship violate physical laws? What makes it so special?

But a photon isn't a particle in any classical sense. It's not like a tiny spaceship, or a "particle" of dust, or anything else. In fact, virtually anything that you might associate with "particle" from classical experience is probably wrong. For example, as demonstrated by [the double-slit experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment), a photon does not travel from point A to point B like a particle.

A photon is not a particle: it's a [quantum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum). That is, it's a parcel of energy that can't be divided.

A photon, not being a classical particle, can't observe anything. Asking what a photon observes makes about as much sense as asking what your voice observes as it travels from your mouth to a listener's ear. We can talk about your voice's effects on the air, and the listener's ear, and what these objects might observe: but your *voice*, the wave traveling in the air, it isn't an object. It's just a system of behavior that describes the effects we will observe on objects.

Comment: Excitations of quantum fields, like photons (and indeed every other fundamental particle), *are* the things we call particles. These things are what particle physics studies. Photons are particles. And photons travel at the speed of light. And this is OK and not at all a problem. Their path between two non-identical places takes zero proper time and finite time as measured by all observers and this is OK and not at all a problem.

Comment: @dmckee yes, *you* call them particles, but no one else does. The word "particle" in the mind of anyone who is not a physicist invokes a very different kind of thing. Then, these people get all confused when a physicist's "particle" isn't anything like the "particle" they know. You can't do a double-slit experiment with dust particles. They aren't waves in any sense. A dust particle can be divided in half with a knife. The conceptual overlap between your "particle" and a classical "particle" is very, very small.

Answer (score 0):

> Special relativity states:

... I'll select and discuss the given statements in some particular order (which may be called "in order of simplicity of discussion") ...

> [...] The observer is (anything [...])

Right. Synonymous to "*observer*" or "*any**thing***", in the context of the theory of relativity, there are also the descriptions "*material point*" or "*principal identifiable point*" or "*participant*".

Of particular relevance is Einstein's foundational guideline that:

[*All our well-substantiated space-time propositions amount to the determination of space-time coincidences [such as] encounters between two or more recognizable material points*](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Foundation_of_the_Generalised_Theory_of_Relativity#ch.3.p.776).

Thereby

- the identity of distinct recognizable observers in coincidences, and
- the distinctiveness of coincidence events due to different subsets of identifiable observers

are presumed self-evident. Arguably then any such coincidence event is in turn considered observable, and any of its observations (by any particular identified observer) is in turn considered a coincidence (of that observer with the corresponding [signal front](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_velocity)).

> The speed of light [...]

It is to be noted that

1. In this context of (geometry and kinematics of) the theory of relativity, "*light*" means any **signal front** of signals exchanged between observers; and
2. The statement under consideration is meaningful (reproducible) only as far as the notion of (how to measure) "*speed*" has been defined (operationally) in the first place.

Einstein expressed this requirement (for the particular notion of "simultaneity") quite memorablý:

[*We thus require a definition of simultaneity such that this definition supplies us with the method by means of which, in the present case, he can decide by experiment whether or not both the lightning strokes occurred simultaneously.*](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Relativity:_The_Special_and_General_Theory/Part_I#Section_8_-_On_the_Idea_of_Time_in_Physics)

As long as this requirement is not satisfied, I allow myself to be deceived as a physicist (and of course the same applies if I am not a physicist), when I imagine that I am able to attach a meaning to the statement of simultaneity.

(I would ask the reader not to proceed farther until he is fully convinced on this point.)

> [...] establish an inertial frame

That's concerning the primary (and especially difficult) method of measurement to be defined (within the General Theory of Relativity):

How to determine whether any two given participants (who were never coincident with each other, but "separated") were **at rest** to each other?

In other words:
How to establish (joint membership of separated observers together in) one "*inertial frame*"; if that's possible at all.

Only once this definition has been selected, and the determination of an "*inertial frame*" did actually succeed, it is possible to speak of (i.e. define and determine) "distance" between participants (or at least: "distance ratios"), "simultaneity" of indications of separated participants, and finally "*speed*".

> The speed of light in a vacuum is always $c$

This statement follows as a theorem, given the usual, suitable definition of "distance between participants $A$ and $B$" as "$c/2$ ping duration", provided $A$ and $B$" were at rest to each other throughout.
(Concretely: the symbolic, literal, non-zero coefficient "$c$" which is part of the distance definition is identified unambiguously as signal front speed; a.k.a. "*speed of light in a vacuum*".)

> The speed of light in a vacuum is always $c$ regardless of the velocity of the observer.

No: this applies only to observers who are involved in the determination of a "*speed*" value (let's say as "starting gate $A$", and as "finish line $B$") and who were therefore at rest to each other (a.k.a. jointly members of the same "*inertial frame*", a.k.a. in equal "*uniform motion*" rather than being individually "accelerated" with respect to some/any "*inertial frame*").

> The laws of physics are the same for all observers in uniform motion.

Certainly **the method how to determine whether** any given observer had been "*in uniform motion*", or not, is the same/reproducible (by anyone who likewise understands/uses the basic notions of "identifiable observers" and their "observable coincidences").

> The observer is (anything that never travels at the velocity $c$).

At least:

- any identifiable observer (who could "carry a signal") cannot have been measured travelling faster than the signal front speed $c$, and
- members of any two "*inertial frames*" cannot have measured their mutual speed (of their mutual "*uniform motion*") as the signal front speed $c$ (otherwise the prerequisite determination of "mutual rest" of observers/participants "within each *inertial frames*" would have failed in at least case to begin with).

> The laws of physics are not the same for anything that does travel at the velocity $c$.

This formulation is confusing any**thing** (observer, participant) which/who is considered observable and identifiable with any "signal itself" (which may be called "**no**thing but the signal having been exchanged between observers").
But yes, certainly **the methods of measurement** used by observers, based on their ability of mutually observing and recognized each other's signals, can not meaningfully be "used by signals themselves".

Therefore, conversely, it is in this sense meaningful

> that Light and Observers have different laws of physics

However, that's perfectly consistent with RT, derived from "*blatantly obvious*" notions as sketched above.